# Linux groups for standard user

Tags: linux, user-accounts, slackware, users

I have recently migrated to Slackware from Debian. I have done this for the purpose of learning, as such, I have a question.

I have looked at the list of groups available on my system via `less /etc/group` and was wondering, which of these groups my user should be a member in order to have a fully functioning desktop environment?

Thanks,
Jack Hunt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to have users members of any of them to get a functioning desktop, however, you may wish to add them to some for convenience.

The `audio` and `video` groups allow the user to make changes to sound and display settings.

The `cdrom` group allows the user to eject the cdrom.

The `users` group is a ready made group for sharing. If all users are members of this group, they can create files with the :users group name, and then add permissions to allow others to access them.

The `sudo` group allows the user to escalate to root (if sudo is installed) for as single command, or for multiple commands.

The `dialout` group is useful if you are on laptop and have a modem.

The `plugdev` group allows popups for removable devices, and to manage them.